# How to remove a drive mapping on win xp

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, drive-letter

I have mapped a drive but now I want it off. How do I remove this mapped drive

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a network share, right click on it and select "Disconnect drive"

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this from the command line or GUI.

Command line - `net use driveletter: /del`

GUI - right click on drive letter, disconnect.